# How to retrieve attribute values of each element in xml as rows in xmlytpe oracle

Tags: xpath, oracle11g, attributes, xquery, xmltype

I am having the following xml

```
<books>
 <book max="30" min="10"> ..  </book>
 <book max="20" min="5"> .. </book>
 <book max="50" min="10"> .. </book>
 <book max="40" min="25"> .. </book>
</books
```

I want the output for this particular xml file as,

MAX_ATTRIB
  MIN_ATTRIB


30        
10




20
5



50
10



40
25

My current query,

```
select MAX_ATTRIB , MIN_ATTRIB from sampletable ,
  xmltable( '/books/book' passing sampletable.xmlcolumn 
    columns MAX_ATTRIB varchar2(20) path '@MAX') ,
  xmltable( '/books/book' passing sampletable.xmlcolumn
     columns MIN_ATTRIB varchar2(20) path '@MIN') ;
```

gives the output like max and min attribute of only book in a xml. How to get all the values.

Answer (score 0):

```
with sampletable as (
    select
        xmltype('
            <books>
             <book max="30" min="10"> ..  </book>
             <book max="20" min="5"> .. </book>
             <book max="50" min="10"> .. </book>
             <book max="40" min="25"> .. </book>
            </books>
        ') as xmlcolumn
    from dual
)
select X.*
from sampletable,
    xmltable('/books/book' passing sampletable.xmlcolumn
        columns
        max_attrib varchar2(20) path '@max',
        min_attrib varchar2(20) path '@min'
    ) X
;
```

Comment: Did it answer your question or not, Nishanth ?